# Como editar projecto online em um servidor?

Tags: cakephp, servidor

Viva!

Estou a desenvolver uma aplicação em cakephp 3, fiz o upload ao servidor, alguém conhece uma forma de continuar a trabalhar no projecto com um IDE mesmo estando no  servidor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes usar o phpstorm ou um IDE que permita a configuração ftp.
Outra forma é acederes aos ficheiros por ftp e editares. Podes usar o Filezilla para acerder ao servidor via FTP, depois clique direito em cima do ficheiro e view/edit.

Comment: Obrigado, queria mesmo evitar ter que a toda a hora ter que fazer download do ficheiro co filezilla.